# why $gt operator does not work without $expr in this case?

Tags: mongodb

```
let criteria={
  $and:[
    {vendorId:req.userData._id},
    {status:APP_CONSTANT.STATUS.ACTIVE},
    {$gt:['$createdAt',{$toDate:{$subtract:[new Date(),1000*60*60*24*days]}}]}
  ]
}
```

that query does not work and gives this error:
MongoError: unknown top-level operator: $gt

but we add $expr then that is working, I don't understand why?

```
let criteria={
  $and:[
    {vendorId:req.userData._id},
    {status:APP_CONSTANT.STATUS.ACTIVE},
    {$expr:{$gt:['$createdAt',{$toDate:{$subtract:[new Date(),1000*60*60*24*days]}}]}}
  ]
}
```

and also one query without $and that does not work, why?
like this:

```
let criteria={
    vendorId:req.userData._id,
    status:APP_CONSTANT.STATUS.ACTIVE,
    $expr:{$gt:['$createdAt',{$toDate:{$subtract:[new Date(),1000*60*60*24*days]}}]}
}
```

and my overall query is that:

```
let criteria={
  $and:[
    {vendorId:req.userData._id},
    {status:APP_CONSTANT.STATUS.ACTIVE},
    {$expr:{$gt:['$createdAt',{$toDate:{$subtract:[new Date(),1000*60*60*24*days]}}]}}
  ]
}

let pipeline=[
  {
    $match:criteria
  },
  {
    $project:{
      year:{$year:'$createdAt'},
      month:{$month:'$createdAt'},
      day:{$dayOfMonth:'$createdAt'}
    }
  },
  {
    $group:{
      _id:{year:'$year',month:'$month',day:'$day'},
      count:{$sum:1}
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You are using aggregation `$gt`, that is the reason. This is the other [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/query/gt/index.html).

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

> `{$gt:['$createdAt',{$toDate:{$subtract:[new Date(),1000*60*60*24*days]}}]}`
>
> *that query does not work and gives this error: MongoError: unknown top-level operator: `$gt`*

The syntax you have used is [aggregation expression syntax of $gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/index.html) conditional operator,

You can read about how aggregation expression works [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions) and [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/),

So you have to use `$expr` if you want to use `$subtract` and `$toDate` operations in condition, because its aggregation expression operator.

> *and also one query without `$and` that does not work, why?*

it seems good to me, but you have to post the error or problem.

#### Suggestion:

If you are using JS/NodeJS in client side you can try below operation so you don't need to use `$expr` operator,

```
let createdAt = new Date();
createdAt.setDate( createdAt.getDate() - 1 ); // subtract 1 day

let criteria = {
  $and:[
    { vendorId: req.userData._id },
    { status: APP_CONSTANT.STATUS.ACTIVE },
    { createdAt: { $gt: createdAt } }
  ]
}
```